# Clickable button inside rendered HTMl in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a React app. In my page I fetch a post content from DB. I want to check that If the post content object has `flag: 'wating_for_accept'` then user see the button that can click on the button and `verifyIt` function gets triggerd.

```
check_accepted_or_not(){
  if(this.post.flag == 'wating_for_accept'){
    render (<div> <Button onClick={this.verifyIt()}> Verify </Button> </div>);
  }else{
    return '';
  }
}

verifyIt(){
  console.log('Vefiry function has been triggered');
}

render() {
  return (
    <h1>{this.post.title}</h1>
    {this.check_accepted_or_not}
  )
}
```

The problem is when function `check_accepted_or_not` renders the button, the `onClick` action of button does not work!

Comment: Hi Sami, see my solution below. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in a reference to the function, not execute it. Considering this sandbox and code below: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-khorana-v5tfl

### Working code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component{
 
  check_accepted_or_not(){
    if(this.props.post.flag == 'wating_for_accept'){
      return (<div> <button onClick={this.verifyIt} > Verify </button> </div>);
    }else{
      return '';
    }
  }

  verifyIt(){
    console.log('Vefiry function has been triggered');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>{this.props.post.title}</h1>
      {this.check_accepted_or_not()}
      </div>

    )
  }
}

App.defaultProps = {
  post: {
    title: "My Post",
    flag: "wating_for_accept"
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: @SamiAlMorshedi awesome! Let me know if you have any questions. Please consider marking as solution :)

Answer (score 0):

just remove parenthesis () from function name

```
<Button onClick={this.verifyIt}> Verify </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch data from DB method would be like below

```
getDataFromDB(){
 //post from DB
  this.setstate({
   flag: post.flag === 'wating_for_accept'
  })
}
```

and render method would be like

```
render() {
  return (
    <h1>{this.post.title}</h1>
    {this.state.flag?
    <div> <Button onClick={() => this.verifyIt}> Verify </Button> </div>
     : ''
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onClick={this.verifyIt()}>` by this you are calling that function directly, you just need to pass the function name like `this.verifyIt`, because on click it will going to execute.

You can directly write a conditon in your render method, this is probably the simpler way.

```
{this.post.flag == 'wating_for_accept' && 
    <div> 
       <button onClick={this.verifyIt}> Verify </button> //Don't write `()` after function name
    </div>
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hymnan)